# Javascript cdn resource fail

Tags: javascript, html, devtools

I follow the instruction, but error report like this

[image]

my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
    <!-- Load Posenet -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
 </head>

  <body>
    <img id='cat' src='./pose/images/aa_090.jpg'/>
  </body>
  <!-- Place your code in the script tag below. You can also use an external .js file -->
  <script>
    var flipHorizontal = false;

    var imageElement = document.getElementById('cat');

    posenet.load().then(function(net) {
      const pose = net.estimateSinglePose(imageElement, {
        flipHorizontal: true
      });
      return pose;
    }).then(function(pose){
      console.log(pose);
    })
  </script>
```

which is exactly the same as 
https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/posenet

Plz do me a favor

Comment: same error here, it looks like the CDN is out of order. Can you download all the required external resources and upload them on your host ?

Comment: hi, should I run a server? I think this is just a simple static html page, and if i choose to use CDN resource, I don't need run a server, right?

Comment: @Pierre And I am totally new to HTML, can you please guide me how to download required external resources

Comment: I can get the js files from both locations, try now maybe the server had a problem https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet

Comment: and then, I need to put it in ?

Comment: try to access them first, you should see the content

Comment: yes, I can see the content, and I can download them, just don't know how to use

Comment: if you download them you need to download all the required files for them to work, since they're depending on other scripts as well

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211627/discussion-between-edee-and-saymoinsam).

Answer (score 1):

I tried the same code snippet and it worked for me without any issue, the cdn also seems to be working when I checked, so the problem could be a few things:

1. Your image does not exist at the given location
2. There was some network issue when you attempted this
3. There is an issue fetching the image locally due to cors : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSRequestNotHttp

Incase the issue persists try downloading the CDN's and the image and host it by following,

1. In the directory of your files run: python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
2. Go to localhost:8000/yourfile.html

Revert back in case of any issues